# Where can I find a copy of Thrilling Tales *First* Edition?

Tags: d20-modern

If I understand correctly, Gareth Skarka (who I tried to contact via Google+, but haven't heard from it yet) worked on a Pulp game called Thrilling Tales.

The first edition was based on a streamlined d20 Modern–derived system called Odyssey System. This was supplanted, in the second (and currently available edition) by Savage Worlds.

I know that Odyssey will be used for his next effort (a sort of Wild West / Cyberpunk / Kung Fu mashup) but I'd like to see the system applied to a (relatively) modern setting, so I'd really like to get a look at the Pulp game.

DriveThrough and RPGNow seem to have only the 2nd edition available. Of course I'd prefer the digital version myself, but if someone can point me to a paper version (assuming it exists) I would be glad, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread at EN World](http://www.enworld.org/forum/general-rpg-discussion/237854-odyssey-system-pathfindering-d20-modern.html), the Odyssey System didn't begin development until 2008. The first edition of *Thrilling Tales* was published in 2006 according to [the *Thrilling Tales* entry at Geekdo](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/43939/thrilling-tales-omnibus-edition).

Therefore, *Thrilling Tales* first edition couldn't be Odyssey System. It's listed at Geekdo as a d20 Modern game. [Originally, the 2nd edition was going to be Odyssey](http://www.enworld.org/forum/general-rpg-discussion/237854-odyssey-system-pathfindering-d20-modern.html), but they [evidently went with Savage Worlds in the end](http://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?mainid=13436).

Despite it probably not being what you're looking for, RPGNow does actually sell [a PDF of *Thrilling Tales: Omnibus Edition*](http://www.rpgnow.com/product_info.php?products_id=20877&it=1) (also known as First Edition) using the d20 Modern system.

As for the Odyssey System, [it looks like Skarka and Adamant's *Far West* will be the first incarnation of the system](http://www.enworld.org/forum/general-rpg-discussion/237854-odyssey-system-pathfindering-d20-modern-3.html#post5579750), and there will be an System Reference Document.

Comment: You are right: Skarka answered personally a few hours ago and he confirms that Odissey has not (yet) been "in print" so far. It was just wishful thinking on my part ;)